# Es 5.5.1 [size] query malformed, no start_object after query name

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

We are upgrading Elasticsearch 1.7 to 5.5 in my company.

Always got this exceptions :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[size]
query malformed, no start_object after query name","line":1,"col":355}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"
[field_sort] failed to parse field [nested_filter]","line":1,"col":355,"caused_by":
{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Expected nested_filter element.","line":1,"col":355,"caused_by":
{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[size] query malformed, no start_object after query 
name","line":1,"col":355}}},"status":400}
```

The query :

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 48,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": null,
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "published_countries.raw": "FR"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "categories",
                        "query": {
                           "term": {
                              "categories.slug.raw": "engrais/engrais-complexes"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "isProductRunOut": {
            "order": "asc"
         }
      },
      {
         "is_featured": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      },
      {
         "total_va": {
            "order": "desc",
            "nested_filter": {
               "size": 12
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "createdAt": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "aggs": {
      "top_12_total_va": {
         "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
               "total_va": {
                  "order": "desc"
               }
            },
            "size": 12
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I know the issue came from the size under the nested_filter because when i remove thoses lines, there is no more issues (in fact, I've got another one). But I don't know how to pass that problem.

I use Elasticsearch php client on a symfony project.

Edit :

Thx to Val, I forgot to add the nested_path in the 3rd sort like said in the doc. So it will look like this :

```
       {
            "total_va": {
                "order": "desc",
                "nested_path": "variants",
                "nested_filter": {
                    "size": 12
                }
            }
        }
```

But I still got the exceptions.

Comment: The issue is with your third `sort` constraint, you have `nested_filter` in there without any `nested_path`... see this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_nested_sorting_example

Comment: Thank you. I forget to add the nested_path. But I still got the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution.
I have to replace that line :

```
"size": 12
```

by

```
"term": {"size": 12}
```